# React-native: communication between components

Tags: react-native

I want to show Login screen only once when the user is not logged in. And then every time the app is started if the user is logged start from the Search screen but it keeps launching from the Login screen. How could i fix that? The logic of navigation is contained in the index.android.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'react-native-md-textinput';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator,
  BackAndroid,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

var Login = require('./LoginPage');
var Search = require('./SearchPage');

class SymptomaReact extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logged: false
    }
  }

  loggedIn(){
    this.setState({logged:true});
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return <route.component navigator={navigator} logged={this.logged} loggedIn={this.loggedIn}{...route.passProps} />
     }

  configureScene(route, routeStack){
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.logged){
      return (
        <Navigator
          configureScene={ this.configureScene }
          style={{ flex:1 }}
          initialRoute={{component: Login}}
          renderScene={ this.renderScene }
        />
      )
    }else {
      return (
        <Navigator
          configureScene={ this.configureScene }
          style={{ flex:1 }}
          initialRoute={{ component: Search }}
          renderScene={ this.renderScene }
            navigationBar={
              <Navigator.NavigationBar
                style={styles.nav}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
            }
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

LoginPage.js

```
`const API="url";
var TOKEN = "";
var Search = require('./SearchPage');

`class LoginPage extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password:'',
      buttonState: 'idle'
    };
    this.attemptLogin = this.attemptLogin.bind(this)
  }

  attemptLogin(){
    console.log(this.props.logged);
    this.setState({buttonState: 'busy'})
    fetch(API+this.state.email+"&password=" + this.state.password)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.message === 'success'){
            TOKEN = responseData.results[0].token;
            this.setState({buttonState: 'success'})
            this.props.navigator.push({
              component: Search,
              passProps: {
                token: TOKEN,
                logged: true,
                loggedIn: this.props.loggedIn
              },
            })
        }
        else {
          this.setState({buttonState: 'idle'})
        }
    }).done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {styles.container}>
          <Image
            source = {require('./logo.png')}
            style={styles.logo}
          />
          <TextField
            style={styles.input}
            label={'Email'}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => {this.refs.pass.focus()}}
            highlightColor={'#009FE3'}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email : text})}
            value={this.state.email}
           />
          <TextField
            ref='pass'
            style={styles.input}
            returnKeyType='send'
            secureTextEntry={true}
            label={'Password'}
            highlightColor={'#009FE3'}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password : text})}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.attemptLogin()}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
```

SearchPage.js

```
class SearchPage extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
       rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2
     });
     this.state = {
       symptoms: [],
       query: '',
       ds: [],
       dataSource: ds
     };
   }

   getSuggestions(query) {
     fetch(API+this.props.token+"&query="+query).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
       this.setState({ symptoms: json.results });
     });
     return this.state.symptoms.filter(symptom => symptom.label);
   }

   componentDidMount(){
     console.log("Received props "+this.props.logged);
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(){
     this.setState({
       dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
     })
   }

   componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({
       dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
     })
   }

   updateListItems(label){
     this.setState({ query: '', ds: this.state.ds.push(label)});
      console.log(this.state.ds + " 1");
   }

   render() {
     const { query } = this.state;
     const symptoms = this.getSuggestions(query);
     const comp = (s, s2) => s.toLowerCase().trim() === s2.toLowerCase().trim();
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={styles.autocomplete}>
         <Autocomplete
           autoCapitalize="none"
           autoCorrect={false}
           blurOnSubmit={true}
           containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
           data={symptoms.length === 1 && comp(query, symptoms[0].label) ? [] : symptoms}
           defaultValue={query}
           onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
           placeholder="Enter your symptoms"
           renderItem={({ index, label, type, value }) => (
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.updateListItems(label)}>
               <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                 {label}
               </Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
           )}
         />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.listview}>
            <ListView
              dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow = {(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
              enableEmptySections={true}>
            </ListView>
          </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you try remove unrelated code? Not too many people want to check so many code for answer a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In componentDidMount of your SymptomaReact component you should check for the current logged in status. Now it is set to false in the constructor and not updated anywhere else unless you log in again through the login component.  The state is not persistent between app shutdowns and launches.

So you should save the logged in state to persistent storage and reload that in the componentDidMount.

Ideally you'd also abstract that away in a store that takes care of the logic and you just get the result in your component itself and work with it.